# The validation errors are not showing using React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using [`React Hook Form`](https://react-hook-form.com) in order to validate some simple inputs :

```
import React from "react";
import useForm from "react-hook-form";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <input
            className="mkn-input"
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="First name"
            ref={register({
              required: true,
              maxlength: 20,
              message: "invalid first name"
            })}
          />
          <span> {errors.firstName && errors.firstName.message}</span>

          <input
            placeholder="Last name"
            className="mkn-input"
            name="lastName"
            ref={register({
              pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i,
              message: "Invalid last name"
            })}
          />
          {errors.lastName && <span> errors.lastName.message</span>}
          <input
            name="age"
            type="number"
            placeholder="Age"
            className="mkn-input"
            ref={register({ min: 18, max: 99 })}
          />
          <input type="submit" className="mkn-btn" />
        </form>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But I'm facing a weird issue with showing that **errors** in the DOM, i also to tried to log them in console but without success, what am I missing ?

the full code :

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Custom Input]

Comment: In RHF v7, `useForm` returns a `fieldState` object which in turn holds the `errors`. But beware that `fieldState` is some kind of proxy object and will always log as empty `{}` even when there are errors!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the `message` in the `required` field, or just query if there is an error:

```
<>
  <input
    name="firstName"
    placeholder="First name"
    ref={register({
      required: 'invalid first name'
    })}
  />
  <span> {errors.firstName && errors.firstName.message}</span>
</>

// Or 
<>
  <input
    placeholder="Last name"
    className="mkn-input"
    name="lastName"
    ref={register({
      required: true,
      pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i
    })}
  />
  {errors.lastName && <span>Invalid last name</span>}
</>

// Or https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#ErrorMessage
```

```
function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <input
            className="mkn-input"
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="First name"
            ref={register({
              required: 'invalid first name'
            })}
          />
          <span> {errors.firstName && errors.firstName.message}</span>

          <input
            placeholder="Last name"
            className="mkn-input"
            name="lastName"
            ref={register({
              required: true,
              pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i
            })}
          />
          {errors.lastName && <span>Invalid last name</span>}
          <input
            name="age"
            type="number"
            placeholder="Age"
            className="mkn-input"
            ref={register({ min: 18, max: 99 })}
          />
          <input type="submit" className="mkn-btn" />
        </form>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Custom Input]

Comment: In v7, `errors` is within `formState`: `const { formState: { errors } } = useForm();`. See [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Handleerrors).

Comment: true formState :  { errorsr } in v7, but it still doesn't log the errors sometimes. I'm experiencing this now with trying to implement custom scroll to events. Quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after installing this component to render associated input's error message.

```
npm install @hookform/error-message
```

Here's an example for implementation:

```
 <input
        {...register("multipleErrorInput", {
          required: "This is required.",
          pattern: {
            value: /d+/,
            message: "This input is number only.",
          },
          maxLength: {
            value: 10,
            message: "This input exceed maxLength.",
          },
        })}
      />
<div>
    {errors.multipleErrorInput && (
                      <div className="text-red-500 mt-4">
                        <span>{errors.multipleErrorInput.message}</span>
                      </div>
                    )}
</div>
```

More info here:
[https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useformstate/errormessage](https://%20https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useformstate/errormessage)

Answer (score 0):

May be a litte bit late but I would like what works for me:

```
import { FC, useState } from "react";
import { useRoles } from "../../hooks";
import Select, { SingleValue } from "react-select";
import { Option } from "../../types/types";
import { UseFormRegister } from "react-hook-form";
import { CreateUserDto } from "../../api";

type Props = {
  onSelect: (role: Option | null) => void;
  register: UseFormRegister<CreateUserDto>;
};

export const RolesSelect: FC<Props> = ({ onSelect, register }) => {
  const { rolesOptions } = useRoles();
  const [selectedRole, setSelectedRole] = useState<SingleValue<Option>>();

  const onChange = (option: SingleValue<Option>) => {
    setSelectedRole(option);
    onSelect(option);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      {...register("roleId", {
        required: "El rol es requerido",
      })}
      name="roleId"
      options={rolesOptions}
      value={selectedRole}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
};
```

And in my form

```
...
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<UserForm>();

return   <RolesSelect
            register={register}
            onSelect={(d) => {
              console.log(d);
            }}
          />
```

Answer (score -3):

In our case (with `react-hook-form@6.x`) this was caused by `React.StrictMode`.

Removing `React.StrictMode` or running the code in production resolves the issue.